# The weird order when concating variables and string with '_'

Tags: linux, bash, path, string, merge

I want to concatenate a variable and a string.

```
while read subject;
do
    pathproc=/projects/guo_lab/cbis/users/yang/DICA_result
    echo  ${pathproc}/${subject}"_"weight
done < /projects/guo_lab/cbis/users/yang/Fulllist_tractography.txt
```

The result is this:

```
_weightrojects/guo_lab/cbis/users/yang/DICA_result/609812419171
```

Why is this happening? The correct form in my mind is:

```
/projects/users/yang/DICA_result/609812419171_weight
```

How can I get this?

By the way, if I delete the `_weight`, it just give:

```
/projects/users/yang/DICA_result/609812419171
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: You're reading `$subject` from a file with Windows line endings. Don't do that, or else strip the trailing CR before use

Comment: Thanks so much, I see, the problem is the file